# New event loop per request Django+ASGI

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, daphne, asgi

I got new event loop on each request even if i use daphne as my server with Django.

**view:**

```
async def main_page(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return HttpResponse(id(loop))
```

**settings:** `ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.asgi.application'`

**start server:**
`daphne project.asgi:application`
or
`python manage.py runserver`
(daphne first in installed apps)

**Logs:**
Starting ASGI/Daphne version 4.0.0 development server at 127.0.0.1:8000

**deps:**
`python==3.10 django==4.2.8 daphne==4.0.0 asgiref==3.7.2`

It works like I'm using WSGI server - new loop on each request (according to new loop id). But id should be the same, isn't it?

How can i fix it?